# How can I get my loop to iterate through my list?

Tags: python, loops

I'm new to programming and python.  I've built a loop that creates a tiled image using one image, and it works great.

```
for left in range(0,iWidth,(logoWidth + xOffset)):
    for top in range (0,iHeight,(logoHeight + yOffset)):
        icopyIm2.paste(logo,(left,top))

icopyIm2.save("tiled_image.png")
```

However, I'd like it to use a series of images, such that each tile is different.  In the parameters for "paste", the "logo" variable is only one image.  I'd like the loop to iterate through a list, for example:

imageList = [pic1.png, pic2.png, pic3.png, pic4.png]

I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: What are the types of `icopyIm2` and `logo`?

Comment: add another for loop around your current ones that gives you logo each time?

Comment: Types are PNG image files, unless I misunderstand.  icopyIm2 is a 900x900 transparent PNG.  The logo is a 300x300 image that tiles nine times, in a 3x3 fashion.

Comment: You have 4 images in the list. Can you have more than 4 tiles? How should that be handled?

Comment: The list is just an example, it probably should be 9 images though, you are correct.  I'm just not sure how to pass the list items into the parameter where I currently have the "logo" (declared and opened up earlier in my code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, you need to figure out how you want to handle the different images when you tile them.  What do you want it to look like if your frame is 3x3 and you have 5 images?

I think the heart of your question is setting up a function with parameters.  The below example makes a tiled images of 3-letter words, which I think is inline with your question.  I have chosen to just loop through the list of inputs repeatedly--no pattern.

```
def make_box(width, height, hits):
    hit_limit = len(hits)
    count = 0
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            print(hits[count % hit_limit], end=' ')
            count += 1
        print()

hit_list = ['bop', 'pow', 'zap', 'bam', 'oof']
box_h = 3
box_w = 4

make_box(box_w, box_h, hit_list)
```

Output:

```
bop pow zap bam 
oof bop pow zap 
bam oof bop pow
```

Comment: This was very useful, thanks Jeff H, specifically the bit about iterating through the hit_list.